# Hamiltonian function of a system of particles governed by Langevin equation of motion

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a system of particles which interact among themselves via some pairwise additive potential ( position dependent ) and I am also considering the collision of the particles with background particles, so there will be dissipation in the system. For such a system the one needs to use Langevin equation of motion :
$m\frac{dv}{dt}=F_{int} -m\gamma v + R(t)$, where,
$\Big<R(s)R(t+s)\Big>=2\pi \gamma m k_B T \delta(t).$

What is the Hamiltonian of the system of particles?